# How to extend the regression line in plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I did a cubic regression on the data below. How can I plot the regression line with x value starting from 0 rather than the minimum x?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':list(range(3,18)),'y':[-4,-2,0,3,5,8,12,17,21,23,24,25,26,26,24]})

x = df['x'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['y'].values.reshape(-1,1)
cubic = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3) 
x_cubic = cubic.fit_transform(x)       
cubic.fit(x_cubic, y) 
model = LinearRegression() 
model.fit(x_cubic, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue') 
pred = model.predict(cubic.fit_transform(x))
ax.plot(x, pred, color = 'red') 
ax.set_xlim(0)
ax.set_ylim(-20)
```

This is what I have now.

[image]

How can I get a plot like this?

[image]

Comment: Just append a few values to `x` before you pass it to `model.predict`? Is there any logic for how to determine the range, for instance, do you always want it to start from 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating and extended x range like this and predicting with your existing model.  Add this to the bottom of your code.

```
ex_x = np.arange(0,4).reshape(-1,1)
ex_pred = model.predict(cubic.fit_transform(ex_x))
ax.plot(ex_x, ex_pred, color='red', linestyle='--')
```

Output:

[image]